# Php newline in Linux (ubuntu) show ^M

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-get-contents

I'm running a PHP script on a Ubuntu server. I'm reading a config file with PHP, do some `preg_replace`s and write back to that file. Doing that with `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`.

But when I do that I see `^M` at the end of each line.

Why is it there and how can I write to a file withou hacing those characters appear? Or is it save to ignore them?

Comment: That's a Windows line separator (CR+LF) being displayed by something expecting a Unix line separator (just LF). Search for those terms and you'll probably find lots of good tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my little script, who replace Windows line separators to UNIX style.

```
<?php
  $in_fp  = fopen( "input.txt", "r" ) or die;
  $out_fp = fopen( "output.txt", "w" ) or die;

  while ( !feof( $in_fp ) ) {
    $buf = fread( $in_fp, 5000 );
    $buf = str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $buf );
    fwrite( $out_fp, $buf );
  }

  fclose( $out_fp );
  fclose( $in_fp );
?>
```